# Switch through top level elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I got a problem in xslt. My problem is, that I got a line in xml, which should be replaced by xsl. I want to replace a informatica file, which was generated by informatica itself.

At first, here is my xsl:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output
  method="xml"
  indent="yes"
  omit-xml-declaration="no"
  media-type="string"
  encoding="ISO-8859-1"
  doctype-system="deftable.dtd"
  /> 
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//AUTOEDIT2[@NAME='%%PARAM']">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../JOB[@JOBNAME]='FILE_STUFF'">
                <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="*"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="../JOB[@JOBNAME]='DATA_STUFF'">
                <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="*"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="../JOB[@JOBNAME]='TANSFER_STUFF'">
                <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="*"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="20150910"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now this is my xml, where the replacement should be done:

```
<SOMETREE>
    <JOB JOBNAME="FILE_STUFF">
        <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="not so important, should be overwritten"/>
    </JOB>
    <JOB JOBNAME="DATA_STUFF">
        <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="not so important, should be overwritten"/>
    </JOB>
    <JOB JOBNAME="TANSFER_STUFF">
        <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="not so important, should be overwritten"/>
    </JOB>
    <JOB JOBNAME="OTHER_STUFF">
        <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="not so important, should be overwritten"/>
    </JOB>
</SOMETREE>
```

So I want to overwrite the value "VALUE" in the AUTOEDIT2 field, related to the JOBNAME.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Best regards
Björn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<xsl:choose>` for that. You can do it through template matching:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
    <xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-system="deftable.dtd" /> 

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AUTOEDIT2[@NAME = '%%PARAM' and ../@JOBNAME = 'FILE_STUFF']" priority="1">
        <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AUTOEDIT2[@NAME = '%%PARAM' and ../@JOBNAME = 'DATA_STUFF']" priority="1">
        <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AUTOEDIT2[@NAME = '%%PARAM' and ../@JOBNAME = 'TANSFER_STUFF']" priority="1">
        <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AUTOEDIT2[@NAME = '%%PARAM']" priority="0">
        <xsl:copy>20150910</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the explicit template priorities: All the `AUTOEDIT2` templates have the same priority by default (calculated from their match expressions by the XSLT engine). Setting an explicit priority defines which template wins a tie.

A tie can occur between any of the first three and the last template. Giving it a lower priority makes sure it is only chosen when an `AUTOEDIT2` element can't match the other three.

Since the desired outcome for the first three `AUTOEDIT2` templates seems to be the same, you could collapse them into one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
    <xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-system="deftable.dtd" /> 

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AUTOEDIT2[@NAME = '%%PARAM' and 
      (
        ../@JOBNAME = 'FILE_STUFF' 
        or ../@JOBNAME = 'DATA_STUFF'
        or ../@JOBNAME = 'TANSFER_STUFF'
      )
    ]" priority="1">
        <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARAM" VALUE="*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AUTOEDIT2[@NAME = '%%PARAM']" priority="0">
        <xsl:copy>20150910</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another way to put the match expression would be:

```
JOB[
    @JOBNAME = 'FILE_STUFF' or @JOBNAME = 'DATA_STUFF' or @JOBNAME = 'TANSFER_STUFF'
]/AUTOEDIT2[@NAME = '%%PARAM']
```